# The markers on the map change position when map is rotated

Tags: android, sdk, here-api

I added markers on my map :

```
ClusterLayer markersClusterLayer = new ClusterLayer();
Collection<MapMarker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
for (GeoCoordinate geoCoordinate : list.get(0).getRoute().getWaypoints()) {
    MapMarker marker = new MapMarker();
    marker.setCoordinate(geoCoordinate);
    markers.add(marker);
}
markersClusterLayer.addMarkers(markers);
map.addClusterLayer(markersClusterLayer);
```

When I rotate my map using my fingers on the device, the marker position changes slightly, going from one side of a road to another for example.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Edit: video showing the problem: youtu.be/mhObjaq72GQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, it was related to the altitude of the point.

I was using

```
PositioningManager.getInstance().getLastKnownPosition()
```

which returned a position with altitude. As a result the marker was "flying" above the map. Setting altitude to 0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not evident from your code, but is it possible that you are using a custom icon for your MapMarkers? If so, remember that the anchor is set to the center of the image by default. This isn't always the correct position.

For example, if your marker image is an arrow, you want to set the anchor to the tip of the arrow. Otherwise it might appear to point to different locations when the map is rotated (event though its center will always be in the same spot). Setting an incorrect anchor can also lead to similar behavior.

You can change the anchor by using the `setAnchorPoint` method.

Comment: I'm using the default marker image. I recorded the problem on video : https://youtu.be/mhObjaq72GQ

Comment: The marker in the video should have the anchor point bottom center, and you can see on the video it's currenty in the center of the image. That's the default anchorpoint. Set the anchorpoint of your marker to bottom center via yourmarker.setAnchorPoint(new PointF(yourimage.getWidth() / 2, yourimage.getHeight()));

Comment: As I said, I'm using the default marker image, so I have no control on it (such as setAnchorPoint). I thought it would be done already as it's an image provided by the SDK.

Comment: I tried using an custom image and using setAnchorsPoint as you said but without success. My code : Image markerImage = new Image();
                        markerImage.setBitmap(markerWithNumber);
                        MapMarker marker = new MapMarker(geoCoordinate, markerImage);
                        marker.setAnchorPoint(new PointF(markerImage.getWidth() / 2, markerImage.getHeight()));
                        markers.add(marker);