# Here maps view goes black when app go in background

Tags: android, here-api

I have recently started using here maps api, and i have encountered some difficulties implementing maps. When app goes in background and i come back to app, map view screen is black. I should mention that i'm using `MapView` and not `MapFragment`. `MapView` is inside fragment view. Beside that map is showing clearly.

```
mapView.setMap(mMap);

        mMap = mapView.getMap();
        mMap.setZoomLevel(16);

        mapMarker = new MapMarker();
        mapMarker.setTitle("Neki naslov");
        mapMarker.setDescription("Neki opis");
        mapMarker.setDraggable(true);

        mapView.setMapMarkerDragListener(mOnDragListener);

        mapMarker.setCoordinate(PositioningManager.getInstance().getLastKnownPosition().getCoordinate());
        mMap.addMapObject(mapMarker);
        mapMarker.showInfoBubble();

        mMap.setCenter(PositioningManager.getInstance().getLastKnownPosition().getCoordinate(),
                Map.Animation.NONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you did not call MapView#onResume() and MapView#onPause() as part of the activity / fragment life cycle. If it is not called, the underlying rendering thread will not be resumed.

@Dusan, your code does not have an image for the marker, so there is no marker to show.

Comment: Working now. Thank you. Why i can't see map marker info bubble although i have set everything and use info bubble exactly it was said in documentation.

Comment: Hello David, please check out my edited question. So problem is that info bubble is not visible.

Comment: One more question David, i don't know if this is included in starter api, but is it possible to restrict some map area, so user can't use it or blurr some parts of maps. For example i would like to show users only map of one country and everything outside that area wouldn't be available for them?

Comment: @Dusan, if you would like to blur other parts of the map my recommendation would be to implement a custom raster tile source and overlay it with some default image for all tiles what you do not want to show.

Comment: Is there any example?

Comment: Please use this class: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics_api_nlp/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-urlmaprastertilesourcebase.html and some code snippits here https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/raster-tiles-custom.html

Comment: Hello David, and what about map marker, how could i make it fixed? Because if i choose some location when map is zoomed to the maximum, and zoom it out, the visual is not looking exatclly. For example i would check with pin mark New York and if i zoom out, pin mark would go down into the ocean.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Exatclly the same problem as this guy had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572251/the-markers-on-the-map-change-position-when-map-is-rotated

Comment: Clustered markers are quite different from the basic marker you used above. Would need more info to help.

Comment: Well i'm setting map marker based on last know position, but i don't know how much more info do i need to provide you?

Comment: What do you mean by "Hello David, and what about map marker, how could i make it fixed? Because if i choose some location when map is zoomed to the maximum, and zoom it out, the visual is not looking exatclly. For example i would check with pin mark New York and if i zoom out, pin mark would go down into the ocean. –" Can you provide a video, screenshot or something to clarify.